# Datetime field dont catch time on a WF

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow

I have this field

[image: Datetime field]

On a workflow, the field catch the actual date and time but it only catch the date and the time is always 00:00

I do this.. Trying 2 times and differente methods to catch the time and add on date but dont work.

[image]

Now, I have this result 15/04/2019 00:00 and I want 15/04/2019 9:02 (or actual datetime)

What can I do to catch the time too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, you can create a Calculated column with the formula “=NOW()”, this column will update when the item is modified, you can create a simple workflow to update the item with some column value changed.

[image]